# In JMeter, are the number of samples expected to be doubled or increased significantly with an increase in the number of users tested?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Moodle version: - 3.9.1+

I am currently testing on Apache JMeter and I am using the scripts provided by Moodle in the 'Make JMeter test plan' option under 'Reports' tab in 'Site Administration'

I am testing for 500 users and 1000 users currently. The configurations are No. of threads = 500, ramp-up period = 200, loops = infinite and duration = 7200 seconds. The same configurations go for 1000 users(just the No. of threads = 1000). I am getting the same number of samples tested after the test completes(i.e after 7200 seconds) for both 500 and 1000 users. Should the number of samples be doubled or increased for 1000 users test or is it okay if I am getting the same number of samples as for the 500 users test?

Also, do the 500 users/1000 users imply concurrent users? How does JMeter work when we say 500 users, does it have a concurrent or sequential approach for the users?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally yes, but unfortunately we're not living in the ideal world.

Take a look at **response time** metric, my expectation is that when you increase the number of threads twice, the response time also increases twice and the **throughput** decreases by the same factor hence you're getting the same number of requests executed for the 2 hours duration.

Consider either generating [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) or inspecting the results using [Graphs](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Graphs) from [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) project (they're installable using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)), this way you will be able to correlate the increasing load ([Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/)) with other metrics ([Response Times Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime) and [Transactions per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond))